# Flutter - After SDK update, emulator not work (version 3.3.10 to 3.7.5)

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, android-emulator, flutter-dependencies

I updated my flutter SDK with "flutter upgrade" command. After update, unfortunately my emulator does not work. I'm getting error messages like this:

```
"build\host\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk" does not exist.
Error launching application on sdk gphone x86.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I tried reinstalling Android Studio, deleting Flutter SDK and installing it then, wiping out my emulator data, creating new emulator, and finally I formatted my PC. None of this worked. In "my computer", only Flutter SDK 3.3.10 is working. I cannot understand why. (Windows 11)

Comment: Try performing flutter clean -> flutter pub get -> flutter pub upgrade in sequence

Comment: @Prashant unfortunately, it didnt work too. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue after upgrading. The only solution I found for now was to downgrade back to my original version.

Check [this](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2844#issuecomment-703526226) on github it might be helpful.

Comment: I also applied the same solution as you did. However, I wasn't satisfied with downgrading to the old version. Then I continued to try and I found the following solution; I switched from Flutter's stable channel to the master channel and it started working again that way. thank you for your suggestion.